# Cannot get response from provided mock service

Tags: angular, jasmine, angular-test

I fail to receive a response from my mock service provided in the test module.

Am I ommiting something?

I get the error:   **TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'service.getUser.subscribe')***

```js
class MockUserService {
  getUser: jasmine.createSpy('getUser').and.returnValue(Observable.of({'name': 'user1'})),
  getUser2: jasmine.createSpy('getUser2').and.returnValue(new BehaviorSubject({'name': 'user2'}))   
}

fdescribe('should use mocked services', () => {
  let component: TestComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestComponent>;
  let service;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [.....],
      providers: [{provide: UserService, useClass: MockUserService}],
      declarations: [TestComponent],
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
    })
    .compileComponents();

    service = TestBed.get(UserService);
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
  });

  it(`should provide mocked service`, () => {
     service.getUser.subscribe(user => {
       console.log(`user: ${user}`);
       expect(user.name).toBe('user1');
     });

    service.getUser2.subscribe(user => {
       console.log(`user: ${user}`);
       expect(user.name).toBe('user2');
     });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the root of your problem is that you were setting those properties using `:` which is trying to set the type, not value, of the property. You should rather use `=` to set the properties equal to the spy created:

```js
class MockUserService {
  getUser = jasmine.createSpy('getUser').and.returnValue(Observable.of({'name': 'user1'})),
  getUser2 = jasmine.createSpy('getUser2').and.returnValue(new BehaviorSubject({'name': 'user2'}))   
}
```

You don't need to create a `MockUserService` class. You can create the jasmine spies right off of the `UserService` instance

```js
describe('should use mocked services', () => {
  ...

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      ...
      providers: [UserService],
      ...
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  ...

  it(`should provide mocked service`, () => {
    spyOn(service, 'getUser').and.returnValue(Observable.of({'name': 'user1'}));
    spyOn(service, 'getUser2').and.returnValue(new BehaviorSubject({'name': 'user2'}));

    service.getUser.subscribe(user => {
      console.log(`user: ${user}`);
      expect(user.name).toBe('user1');
    });

    service.getUser2.subscribe(user => {
      console.log(`user: ${user}`);
      expect(user.name).toBe('user2');
    });
  });
});
```